# Complexity status of restricted k-clique

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, time-complexity, space-complexity, logspace

**Restricted** **$k$-clique:**

**Input:** $(G,v,k)$ where $v$ is vertex in $V$

**Output:** k-clique containing vertex $v$.

What is the space and time complexity status of this **Restricted** **$k$-clique** problem?

Is it same as **$k$-clique** problem?

I trying to show this problem is in $L$ or $NL$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is essentially same as the Clique problem. Imagine a clique containing $n$ nodes. Your problem is then asking for a Clique containing $n-1$ nodes, such that all of them are adjacent to vertex $v$. $v$ is connected to all vertices in the graph. The problem is still NPComplete.

Comment: If we solve **Restricted** **$k$-clique** problem then we can solve $k$-clique problem. But not other way round.

Comment: The much easier problem of approximating Clique itself is NPComplete ( http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1991-focs-fglss.pdf). And if we consider the largest clique (of size $n$), finding the clique of size $n-1$ is obviously NPComplete.

Comment: What @TheoryQuest1 tries to explain I think is that a $k$-clique in a graph $G$ is exactly a restricted $k+1$-clique containing the vertex $v'$ in the graph $G'$ where $G'$ is obtained from $G$ by adding a fresh vertex $v'$ connected to all vertices of $G$.

Comment: I should have put it that way. Much more accessible.